# Will a dipole placed inside a dipole rotate for considerably long time

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that a current loop acts as a dipole and when it is placed in a dipole it starts rotating and does rotate until the fields go away.

If I place a dipole inside another fixed dipole, will it also rotate similarly?

Comment: "when it is placed in a dipole" What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no situation matching your opening statement. You need more details. Are you talking about to electric or magnetic dipoles?  How are they structured or constrained?
A compass needle, if placed the field of another magnetic dipole (like that of the earth), will undergo damped oscillations until it is in line with the field.

Comment: The inside dipole is free to rotate and the outer dipole is fixed. Both are magnetic dipoles, only inside one is solid i. e. containing both poles in a single piece, and outer dipole is having set up as in a current loop's outer dipole(magnetic). I know there is an unstable and a stable condition for oscillations of inside dipole, just need more clarity.